# Checking current value of an array, C#

Tags: c#

I have created an array with a predefined length of 2. And I have a method for adding items to the array.

The code for it is:

```
 public void addItem(T item)
 {
   Array.Resize(ref items, items.Count() + 2);
   items[items.Count() - 2] = item;
 }
```

Now, what I want to do is that it first has to check the array size and see if the array is full of not. If the array is full, it should double the size of the array. If its not full then it shouldn't do nothing. So, I'm wondering if I can make this possible with an if statement?

EDIT: Im writing an collection class, thats why I need to check the array

Comment: Sounds like you are reinventing the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class? May I ask why?

Comment: Why don't you use a `List<T>` is has this functionality already built-in?

Comment: reinventing wheel is a serious business

Comment: Im creating an Collection class, thats why

Comment: But such class already exists. Why do you need to create it once again?

Comment: It's rare these days to need to write code using arrays - the [collection classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.aspx) (especially the [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx)) are usually a better way to go.

Comment: I guess this is homework, which is why he can't use the built-in stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You should really get familiar with the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) which already uses this functionality by default:

[`List.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) for example calls `EnsureCapacity`:

```
private void EnsureCapacity(int min)
{
    if (this._items.Length < min)
    {
        int num = (this._items.Length == 0) ? 4 : (this._items.Length * 2);
        if (num < min)
        {
            num = min;
        }
        this.Capacity = num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I am writing an collection class and Im not allowed to use the generic collections

Comment: So is this homework. Ok, but it's not clear what problem you actually have. You could look at the implementation of `List<T>`(i used `ILSpy`) to see how MS did it.

Answer (score 0):

You should know, that you do not learn anything, if you do not do your homework on your own

but try something like this:

if count > size -2
than resize: size*2
else //do nothing

maybe you can add a feature like:
if count < size / 4
than shift entries to the front and resize: size/2
else //nothing

hope this advise is useful for you